# Set text field size in GXT4.0 through CSS

Tags: css, extjs, gwt, gxt

Currently I am new to gxt 4.0 and implementing triton theme in my project.

There is one issue related to text field.By implementing triton theme, the height of text field is 30px, I have to set it to 24px.

I do not want to set the height in the code.

How can I set it through CSS which will apply to all the text field or there is another way to set the code without affecting the code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new class that extends TextField and you can override the height or any other property of the text field. It will be applied throughout your application.